# Android Facebook: getPermissions is not working

Tags: android, facebook, permissions

I am trying to determinate if my user have a publish permission, I am runnign the next code for it:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private void post(Bundle postParams){
    // Check for publish permissions    
    List<String> permissions = Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions();
    if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
        // Ask for permission logic
    }
    else{

        // Post logic
    }
}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset) {
    for (String string : subset) {
        if (!superset.contains(string)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However even if I remove permission from my application account in facebook `Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions()`  return me a list with that permission inside.

What am I doing wrong? How can I clear permission cache on facebook?

Answer (score 1):

The permissions that your session thinks it has is cached on the device, so once it gets those permissions, it always thinks it has those permissions. However, a publish request will fail if the user removes it from the website. You can see how Facebook recommends you handle those errors here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/

There's really no way of knowing that a user has removed a permission from the website until you make a request.

If you want to know the exact set of permissions your app has at any time, you can always make a graph request to /me/permissions yourself.